# Finding max element in Arraylist of integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm attempting to create a function that allows you to pass in a ArrayList and return the max element. I have been unable to figure out a correct solution because of the data type being passed in is not primitive. I've also tried converting the ArrayList to ArrayList without success. Here is my (incorrect) code thus far:

```
public static void maxArrayListValue(ArrayList<int[]> arrayList) {
    int maxArrayListValue = arrayList.get(0);   // set first arrayList element as highest

    for (int index=1; index < arrayList.size(); index++) {  // cycle through each arrayList element
        if (maxArrayListValue < arrayList.get(index)){      // if new element is > than old element
        maxArrayListValue = arrayList.get(index);           // replace with new maxValue
        maxArrayListIndex = index;                          // record index of max element
        }
    }
    return maxArrayListValue;
}
```

Any input would be apprecieated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method isn't returning anything, and I think you want to iterate the values in each array. Something like,

```
public static int maxArrayListValue(List<int[]> arrayList) {
    int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int[] arr : arrayList) {
        for (int v : arr) {
            if (v > maxVal) {
                maxVal = v;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly; the first loops through each array in the arraylist and the second loops through each element in each array?

Comment: You have a `List<int[]>` so we first iterate the `int[]` contents of your `List<>` and then you have it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. Just use `java.util.Collections.max(arrayList)`;

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, I thought you could only use collections on primitive data types? I get the error: "The method max(<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<int[]>)".

Comment: If your collection elements don't have a natural ordering, you have to provide a `Comparator` as the second element.